# Tooltip coming out from canvas in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, d3.js

I have list of bars that are being displayed on the canvas and when I hover on the bar their respective values are getting displayed but that value is coming out of canvas at down. So please help and suggest thank you in advance!!
Here is my html file where I have my tooltip implementation

```
var margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 80,
            left: 40
        };
        var width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right;
        var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


        var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);


        var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

        var hAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient('bottom')
                .ticks(4).tickSubdivide(2).tickSize(5, 5, 0)
                .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"))

        var vAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient('left');
        var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
                .style('position', 'absolute')
                .style('background', '#f4f4f4')
                .style('padding', '5 15px')
                .style('border', '1px #333 solid')
                .style('border-radius', '5px')
                .style('opacity', 'o');

        var line = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) {
                    return xScale(d.date);
                })
                .y(function(d) {
                    return yScale(d.value);
                })
                .interpolate("linear")
                .tension(0.9);


        function render(filterByDates) {


            d3.select('svg').remove();

            if (filterByDates) {
                selectDate = true;
                //tempData = fliterdata;
                console.log("before date fliter data", fliterdata);
                var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById('field1').value);
                var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById('field2').value);

                tempData = fliterdata.filter(function(d) {
                    console.log(date1, date2);
                    //  alert(date1);
                    return d.date >= date1 && d.date <= date2;


                });
                console.log("After date tempData", tempData);
            }


            xScale.domain(tempData.map(function(d) {
                        return d.date;
                    }) .sort(function(a, b) {
                        return a - b;
                    }
                    )
            );

            yScale.domain([0, d3.max(tempData, function(d) {
                return +d.value;
            })]);

            var svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .append("g")

                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            svg

                    .append('g')
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(hAxis)
                    .selectAll("text")
                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
                    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                    .attr("dy", "-.55em")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

            svg
                    .append('g')
                    .attr("class", "yaxis")
                    .call(vAxis)

            if (chartType == 'bar') {
                svg
                        .selectAll(".bar") //makes bar
                        .data(tempData)
                        .enter().append("rect")
                        .attr("class", "bar")
                        .style("fill", "teal")
                        .attr("x", function(d) {
                            return xScale(d.date);
                        }).attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
                        .attr("y", function(d) {


                            return yScale(d.value);
                        }).attr("height", function(d) {

                            console.log("as", d.value);
                            return height - yScale(d.value);
                        })
                        //.text(function(d){return d.value + "%";})
                        .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                            tooltip.transition()
                                    .style('opacity', 3)

                            tooltip.html(d.value)
                                    .style('left', (d3.event.pageX) + 'px')
                                    .style('top', (d3.event.pagey) + 'px')
                            d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.5)
                        }).on('mouseout', function(d) {
                    tooltip.transition()
                            .style('opacity', 0)
                    d3.select(this).style('opacity', 1)
                });
            }

            if (chartType == 'line') {
                svg.append("path") // Add the line path.
                        .data(tempData)
                        .attr("class", "line")
                        .attr("d", line(tempData));
            }

        }

        d3.json(jsonURL, function(data) {

            myData = data; //data from json in mydata
            myData.forEach(function(d) {


                d.date = new Date(d.date);
                d.date = new Date(d.date + " UTC");
            });
       console.log( 'mydatajson', myData);
            $("#listbox").on("click", function() {

                var key = $(this).val();
                //console.log("key:", key);
                var value = $('#listbox option:selected').text();


                selectop = String(key);
                selectop= "val0"+selectop;
                fliterdata=myData.filter(function(d){
          return d[key].slice(3) ==value;
                }).map(function(d){

                   return {date:d.date,value:d[selectop].toString().replace(",",".")};

                });
                tempData=fliterdata;
                if (selectDate)
                    render(true);
            });
        });

        function selectChartType(type) {
            chartType = type;
            render(true);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi..anybody around!!